# Insert and then select in VF controller giving List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, soql

I am Inserting into a CPQ quote object like this

```
  SBQQ__Quote__c qt = new SBQQ__Quote__c(SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = dsOpportunity.getId(),
                                                               SBQQ__Account__c = dsAccount.getId(),
                                                               SBQQ__PricebookId__c = pricebookid);
  Database.SaveResult dsQuote = Database.insert(qt, false);
```

And after that I am inserting into Quoteline also. Both Quote and Quote line getting inserted properly.

After that I am trying to generate a PDF using VF page like this

```
 PageReference pdf = Page.SendQuoteInMail;
 pdf.getParameters().put('QuoteId',dsQuote.getId()); 
 Blob reportPdf=pdf.getContent();
```

and the controller of VF page is like this

```
public with sharing class SendQuoteInMailController {
private String QuoteID {get; set;}
public List<SBQQ__Quote__c> QuoteToRender{get; set;}

public SendQuoteInMailController() {
    this.QuoteID=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('QuoteId');
    System.debug('this.QuoteID >>>>'+this.QuoteID);
    this.QuoteToRender=[select Id,SBQQ__Account__r.Name,SBQQ__PrimaryContact__r.Name,SBQQ__SalesRep__r.Name,SBQQ__StartDate__c,SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c, SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c,(select id,SBQQ__CustomerPrice__c,SBQQ__Product__r.Name,SBQQ__ListPrice__c,SBQQ__SpecialPrice__c,SBQQ__Quantity__c from SBQQ__LineItems__r)   from SBQQ__Quote__c where id =:this.QuoteID];
    System.debug('this.QuoteToRender >>>>'+this.QuoteToRender.size());
}
}
```

Below is the debug log and I am always getting this error
**System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**

[image]
But I am sure Quote and quote line data got inserted succesfully.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pdf.getContent();` must be in a transaction that starts after the one in which the data is inserted (and committed) as `pdf.getContent();` runs in its own transaction. So call `pdf.getContent();` from a `@future` method or after a page redirect.